# Why can't I create a graph with insert query Jena dataset

Tags: java, jena

I used an insert SPARQL query, like this:

```
PREFIX dc: <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/>
PREFIX ns: <http://example.org/ns#>

INSERT DATA
{
   GRAPH <http://example/test> { <http://example/book2>  ns:price  42 }
   GRAPH <http://example/test> { <http://example/book3>  ns:price  55 }
}
```

When I use a Dataset in TDB, this query was successful. But when I use a memory Dataset, Jena throws this error.

```
com.hp.hpl.jena.shared.JenaException: No such graph: http://example/test
```

Using a memory Dataset, is it not possible to create a graph with an insert query? And why?

**P.S.**

I used v2.10.0. And I created dataset like this:

```
Dataset dataset = DatasetFactory.create(other_dataset);
```

So I change the Jena version and change to use the '*DatasetFactory.createMem()*'.

It operated without problem .

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which version? Nowadays v2.10.1 and several before that, the in-memory dataset automatically adds new graphs unless you asked for a fixed one.

DatasetFactory.createMem() vs DatasetFactory.createMemFixed().

Comment: Aha! I thought this must exist now.

Answer (score 0):

The default memory dataset is (as you've found) just fixed collection of models (graphs). It doesn't know how to create graphs on demand. (TDB does -- graphs are cheap in quad stores)

I can't see a suitable dataset in jena (although it may well be there) but it's not hard to write one:

```
// This makes graphs on demand
DatasetGraphFactory.GraphMaker maker = new DatasetGraphFactory.GraphMaker() {
    public Graph create() {
        return new GraphMem();
    }
};

// Make a datasetgraph which creates graphs when required, and wrap it as an API dataset
Dataset onDemand = DatasetImpl.wrap(new DatasetGraphMaker(maker));
```

Comment: I solved the problem thanks to you. And, thank you who reworked the question.

Comment: No problem. I'll check whether it already exists in jena. *cough* hit accept answer *cough*